# Java Create SQlite DB without physical file

Tags: java, spring, sqlite

I am using Java, Spring .

Need to create Sqlite DB(with create table statements) On the Server(Java) and send DB to device.

How can I create sqlite db and get InputStream or bytes array without creating physical file?

Comment: You can create an "in memory" SQLite DB.  It will go "poof" when closed, of course.  And I'm not sure that there's any way to get an image of it so you can "ship" that.

Comment: Is it too expensive to create the DB on the device? Nevertheless, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: (Can't you just create the DB in the file system?  Can your app not use the file system at all?)